# mysql: Non-grouped items collapse on using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Problem:** I am currently grouping a table in `mysql`by one column and this will collapse other columns to one row for each group.
How can I control which row will be displayed after the group by?
 For example, for one of the columns I would like to sort it and then have only the top column in each group be displayed.

Comment: Please add sample data and your expected output to the question.

Comment: Yes, please do add those data for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Most cases where this comes up, you don't really want aggregation.  You want to filter the data.  So, say you have a bunch of records for `entities` that are updated over time.  If you want the most recent row for each entity, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.created_at = (select max(t2.created_at) from t t2 where t2.entity_id = t.entity_id);
```

However, the correct thing for you to do is probably to delete this question.  Ask another question with sample data, desired results, and the query that you are using.